# Issue with where to put .innerHTML in my JS code

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple assignment for one of my modules and I've come into this problem for the 3rd or 4th time. My problem is that as my code shows below when I put the .innerHTML attribute on the first line it does not work at all and there is no error in the console window. When I place the it after the info.innerHTML on the second line it does work. I have asked a tutor and he is stuck on why this is happening

```
var info = document.getElementById("pOutput").innerHTML;
info = "Sum: " + sum + "<br>Average: " + avg;

var info = document.getElementById("pOutput");
info.innerHTML = "Sum: " + sum + "<br>Average: " + avg;
```

Comment: You're going to need two variables: one to keep track of the string, and one to keep track of the element.

Comment: Side note, `GetElementById` needs to be `getElementById`

Comment: @j08691 oh sorry I just typed that out wrong when I was writing up the question. It's correct in the code

Comment: @Pointy Is that good practice or something that needs to be done? I'll start to do that in my code for no on to avoid any issues. Thanks!

Comment: "*I have asked a tutor and he is stuck on why this is happening*" your tutor shouldn't be advising on JS, given this is not abnormal behaviour. It's not even abnormal outside JS, either.

Answer (score 0):

The second variation that you've included is correct but needs getElementById() instead of GetElementById().

The top lines are incorrect because you are overriding the variable info with your string, not writing it into innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `info` to `innerHTML`, it's *getting* the value. You need to set `info` to `document.GetElementById("pOutput")`, and then set `info.innerHTML`:

```
var info = document.getElementById("pOutput");
info.innerHTML = "Sum: " + sum + "<br>Average: " + avg;
```

Comment: Also worth noting - strings are immutable in JS, so you can't just get a reference to one and change it. Moreover, object references aren't going to change the old reference when assigning a new one `info = document.getElementById("pOutput")` followed by `info = someOtherHTMLElement` will not affect the previous object at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because in the first bit of code, you capture the value of the innerHTML property of the element. For example, if your element has `<div></div>` inside it, the value of info will be "`<div></div>`". If you modified the innerHTML of the element after, the value of info would still be `<div></div>`. On the contrary, in the second bit of code, what you capture is a reference to the element. Therefore you can modify its properties and it will reflect on the element itself. The reason why this happens is explained [here](https://www.educative.io/collection/page/5679346740101120/5707702298738688/5685265389584384?affiliate_id=5082902844932096&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=platform2&utm_content=ad-1-dynamic&gclid=Cj0KCQiA14TjBRD_ARIsAOCmO9ajEEAZh3vGNO3vBebJvGDsgk_DN9gNqrL5ujsRvTLCaCVhX-NE3aoaAlJHEALw_wcB) but to make it simple, some types (like strings and numbers) are copied as values and some other types (like Objects) are copied as references.